# How to make img scale in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this huge image (I know, bad, will be replaced by some smaller ones for different viewport-sizes) that I want to display next to another div. Both elements are inside a flexbox, so flex-items.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/aedtyj9y/

My problem is that the image is way too big. What I would want is the image to take up all the space of `#test` which itself should only maximum take up 30% of the whole horizontal space, so having 70% of the `main class='flex-container'` for `details` and the rest for a an image that is contained in the 30% (preferably cropped instead of scaled)

Sounds easy, right? Just add `max-width:30%` to `#test`!

WRONG! https://jsfiddle.net/04wohehh/

Image is still too big.

So what, just add `max-width:100%; max-height:100%;` to the img itself, right?

Again, not working as intended:

https://jsfiddle.net/wqhtqq8d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you looking for?

- set `flex: 0 70%` in `.details`
- set `flex: 0 30%; display: flex; align-items: center` in `#test`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#info {
  background-color: #2aabd2;
  max-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#info nav {
  max-width: 5%;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

main {
  background-color: red;
}

.details {
  flex: 0 70%
}

#test {
  flex: 0 30%;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

.testimage {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10vh #111;
}
```

```html
<section id="info" class="flex-container">
  <nav id="node">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Other</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main class="flex-container">
    <div class="details">
      Blablablablabla
    </div>
    <div id="test">
      <img class="testimage" src="http://placehold.it/2000x2000">
    </div>
  </main>
</section>
```

Comment: According to the provided jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/aedtyj9y/ as there were multiple ones) this is already done via class `flex-container`, isn't it?

Comment: I am sorry, you edited in between, so I just read your first point! Mea culpa! Nevertheless the `main` still had `display: flex` via the class `flex-container`

Comment: Yes, but that's my point. You did not add that, it was already there just encoded differently :) But let's end this here, I am just nitpicking.

Comment: You removed `#info nav { max-width: 5%;}` other than that it is great!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take: https://jsfiddle.net/hq2ppqr5/

What I did:

1. Added back in the `max-width: 100%` and `min-width: 100%` for
   `img, embed, object, video` in order to ensure it the img does not
   overflow/break out of it's "cage"
2. Removed `margin-left: auto;` from `#info main` as it is
   unnecessary, flexbox should take care of that!
3. Added `flex-grow:1;` to `#info main` to let it fill up the
   remaining (horizontal) space!
4. added `flex-grow: 1` to the first child of the `section`
5. Added a background-color to the `nav`
6. Changed `main` to `section` (during fiddling around :))

**One note though**: it still looks different in firefox and chromium, but this seems to be an issue with padding.

Firefox evenly centers both flex-items, while chromium puts the image at the bottom. I am not sure what exactly is causing this.

Comment: Those rendering differences between chrome and firefox are annoying... I even added another reset.css but no luck... grrr!

Comment: Yup, but they only appear above ~1024 pixels width or so for me. Really odd. Anyway, I'd go for @dippas solution if I were you. I think the solution with `flex-shrink` is nicer than dealing with widths manually!